# .Net MVC application always redirects to login for public page

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Environment: .Net 4.6.2, MVC 5.2.4, VS 2017. After adding a public/default page to my existing web application and decorated the controller class with `[AllowAnonymous]`, in the local debug environment, my application always show login page with URL localhost:12345. Below are what I've done, what am I missing? TIA

1. route to default page in RouteConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "mydomain.web.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

2. Controllers/HomeController

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       return View();
    }
}
```

3. check IIS express config

```
<site name="mydomain.web" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
          <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="E:\mydomain.web" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
          <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:52792:localhost" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

4. my Views/Home/Index.cshtml

```
@{ Layout = null;}

<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Index</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

5. web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" name="AuthClientUser"
           timeout="60" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies" 
           path="/">
     </forms>
</authentication>
```

6. http traffic

> request: http://localhost:12345 response: 302 found, location:
>   /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f

Answer (score 0):

Please never mind. The authorization section of web.config denies all anonymous users I forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

it is probably the Forms tag in your web.config is causing your app to call the url "~/Account/Login" as it thinks your user is not authenticated but there is no such Route in your controller.

try to change the form LoginUrl in your config to the existing Index route "~/Index" if you want or create a new Action to handle this route.